# Validating a string length using Apache-NiFi

Tags: csv, replace, apache-nifi

In my flowfile, I need to verify a column content has certain number of strings. If not, I will replace it with a text. To implement this, I have used `UpdateRecord` processor with :

```
Record Reader : CSV
Record Writter : CSV
Replacement Value strategy : Literal Values

/my_column : ${field.value:replaceAll('[a-z]+|[a-z]+','Wrong')
              :replaceAll(${field.value:length():le(8)},'Undefined')}
```

I have also used `:replaceAll(${field.value:count():le(8)},'Undefined')`

But none of them worked as expected. It didnt replace wrong number of strings with `Undefined`

Input :

```
id,name,my_column
1,sachith,9403039409445
2,nalaka,rwed222
3,muhandiram,45544
```

Expected :

```
id,name,my_column
1,sachith,9403039409445
2,nalaka,Wrong
3,muhandiram,Undefined
```

PS : Added sample input and output after first comment.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question with a minimal example of: input, desired output, actual output with your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. In your expression, there are no conditional expressions.

```
/my_column    ${field.value:find('[a-z]+')
               :ifElse(
                ${field.value:replace(${field.value},'Wrong')},
                ${field.value:length():le(8)
                :ifElse(
                 ${field.value:replace(${field.value},'Undefined')},
                 ${field.value}
              )})}
```

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks for the answer.